# Could not move uploaded file to destination Drupal 8

Tags: file-upload, drupal, upload, drupal-8

I have a trouble gatting drupal to upload files (images, configuration, I guess anything).
The error message is:

```
The file could not be saved because the upload did not complete.
File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.
```

When I go to log it says:

```
Upload error. Could not move uploaded file multimedia.svg to destination public://2017-03/multimedia.svg.
```

I already read about permissions and here they are:

```
sites/default/files - 770
sites/default/files/2017-03 - 770
/tmp - 1777
```

However I'm able to upload & install themes and modules without any ploblems at all.
So what could it be? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. switch php mode from "Apache module (mod_php)" to "Fast CGI (mod_fcgid)"
2. core\includes\file.inc
   function file_prepare_directory()
   should return true

see [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sites_default_files-944582-120.patch)
or just temporarily put

```
return true;
```

instead of

```
return $writable;
```

in the function